# How do you change an Opportunity's Record Type in the web UI?

Tags: record-type, opportunity

Originally our org only had one record type for opportunities but we've since added a second. I want to manually change a few opportunities to this new type. However, the Opportunity Record Type field doesn't appear to be something I can change. I would have expected a drop down of some sort.

Is there any way to change an existing opportunity's record type in the web UI? If not, can it be changed at all? Do I have to delete it and recreate it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you cant edit the record type of the object in edit mode.

If you go to the detail view of the page, you should see a field called record type with the link [change] next to it.

If you dont see that, edit the layout to add the record type field to the layout in question:

---

[image]

---

Comment: "Opportunity Record Type" is the name of the field to add to the page layout.

Comment: And verify that the appropriate profiles have the permissions to change it.

Comment: Hmm, I had already added the Opportunity Record Type to the layout but there is no [Change] next to it (there isn't anything next to it). This is from a System Administrator profile.

Comment: 2 things, one: check that you have more than 1 record type created for the opportunity. two: make sure the other record types are available to the profile attached to the test user.